# mySQL counting instances of field value

Tags: mysql

I have a database table like this:

```
id    slot1   slot2   slot3
---------------------------------
1     10      10      0
2     0       0       10
3     0       10      0
```

I need a SQL statement to find out how many instances of '10' there are in the whole table. So for above, it'd give me 4 as the answer. I'm not sure what method I could use...

Is there an logical way of doing this, or do I have to pull all records `WHERE slot1=10 OR slot2=10 OR slot3=10` and count them afterwards?

Comment: `sum(case when slot1 = 10 then 1 else 0 end + case when slot2 = 10 then 1 else 0 end + case when slot3 = 10 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: A database table is not a spreadsheet. Fix your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with conditional aggregation.

```
select count(case when slot1=10 then 1 end) +
       count(case when slot2=10 then 1 end) + 
       count(case when slot3=10 then 1 end)
from tbl
where 10 in (slot1,slot2,slot3)
```

With MySQL, the conditions can be simplified to

```
select sum(slot1=10)+sum(slot2=10)+sum(slot3=10)
from tbl
where 10 in (slot1,slot2,slot3)
```

Each condition returns 1 or 0 depending on truthfulness.

Comment: can the anonymous downvoter state the reason please?